# Why isn't there a big HTM machine already?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I've been reading a bit about [Hierarchical Temporal Memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_temporal_memory) and [Memory Prediction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-prediction_framework). I found a great paper: [How the brain might work: A hierarchical and temporal model for learning and recognition](http://alpha.tmit.bme.hu/speech/docs/education/02_DileepThesis.pdf), [Dileep George's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dileep_George) dissertation for his PhD at Stanford.

I was searching google, to see if such a big network has been deployed somewhere, but I found no results. I know that [Numenta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numenta) has such systems, but there is no information about the size, and what the machine can do. Does that mean that this method isn't good enough?

Comment: "Why not?" questions are often hard to answer.